# How to find a part of string in another string?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, split

I need to read data from the file.

```
f=open("essay.txt","r")
my_string=f.read()
```

The below string which starts with `\nSubject:` and ends with `\n` is in the `my_string`

```
Example:
"\nSubject: Good morning - How are you?\n"
```

How can I search for the string which starts with `\nSubject:` and ends with `\n` ?
Is there any python function to search for particular pattern of a string ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's better to just search through the file line by line instead of loading it all into memory with `.read()`. Every line ends with `\n`, no line starts with it:

```
with open("essay.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('Subject:'):
            pass
```

To search for it in that string:

```
import re
text = "\nSubject: Good morning - How are you?\n"
m = re.search(r'\nSubject:.+\n', text)
if m:
    line = m.group()
```

Comment: My questions is to search for a string which starts with Subject and ends with \n in my_string

Answer (score 2):

Try startswith().

```
str = "Subject: Good morning - How are you?\n"

if str.startswith("Subject"):
    print "Starts with it."
```